# Running Head with Query Cross link

Tags: cross-referencing, header-footer, two-column, page, hyperlink

I have try to make a query cross link in the running head, but Query corss linking not shown in PDF, other places working fine. My MWE is below

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter

\def\ps@heading{%
    \def\@oddfoot{}
    \def\@evenfoot{}
    \def\@oddhead{\hfil\rightmark\hfil}%
    \def\@evenhead{\hfil\leftmark\hfil}%
}

\def\AQ#1{\leavevmode\vadjust{\smash{\llap{\hbox to 70pt{#1\hfill}}}}}

\pagestyle{heading}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\section{Section Title}

\markboth{Left side margin}{Right side\protect\AQ{AQ2} aaaaamargin}

The current\protect\AQ{AQ1} study was a subanalysis of the CENC study, approved by local institutional review boards at each study site. CENC assesses V/SM for psychological, cognitive, and physical symptoms at fixed intervals based on an injury- or deployment-related index date that is established through the PCE mapping process. Only baseline data were used for the current analysis. This study conformed to all state and federal research regulations, including federal ethical standards. All participants provided written informed consent to participate.

\clearpage
The current study was a subanalysis of the CENC study, approved by local institutional review boards at each study site. CENC assesses V/SM for psychological, cognitive, and physical symptoms at fixed intervals based on an injury- or deployment-related index date that is established through the PCE mapping process. Only baseline data were used for the current analysis. This study conformed to all state and federal research regulations, including federal ethical standards. All participants provided written informed consent to participate.

\clearpage
The current study was a subanalysis of the CENC study, approved by local institutional review boards at each study site. CENC\protect\AQ{AQ2} assesses V/SM for psychological, cognitive, and physical symptoms at fixed intervals based on an injury- or deployment-related index date that is established through the PCE mapping process. Only baseline data were used for the current analysis. This study conformed to all state and federal research regulations, including federal ethical standards. All participants provided written informed consent to participate.
\clearpage


The current study was a subanalysis of the CENC study, approved by local institutional review boards at each study site.\protect\AQ{AQ3} CENC assesses V/SM for psychological, cognitive, and physical symptoms at fixed intervals based on an injury- or deployment-related index date that is established through the PCE mapping process. Only baseline data were used for the current analysis. This study conformed to all state and federal research regulations, including federal ethical standards. All participants provided written informed consent to participate.
\clearpage


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\vadjust` material migrates from the horizontal list to the surrounding vertical list. However, the header is set into a `\hbox` (in fact in a couple nested `\hbox`es), so there is no surrounding vertical list. Therefore it disappears.

You can check this by putting the `\AQ` stuff in the main text also in a `\hbox`. It will then also disappear.

However, you can put your header stuff in a `\parbox`, and then it will be in a vertical list, and the `\AQ` text will appear.

```
\def\@oddhead{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hfil\rightmark\hfil}}
```